# How to fix NestJS @InjectModel() dependency error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

rememberLink.scheme.ts

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document, Types } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from 'src/users/schemas/users.schema';

export type RememberLinkDocument = RememberLink & Document;

@Schema({versionKey: false, timestamps: true})
export class RememberLink {
    @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
    code: string;

    @Prop({ type: Types.ObjectId, ref: User.name, required: true })
    user: User;
}

export const RememberLinkSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(RememberLink);
```

remember-password.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { RememberPasswordController } from './remember-password.controller';
import { RememberPasswordService } from './remember-password.service';
import { RememberLink, RememberLinkSchema } from './schemas/rememberLink.schema';

@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{
            name: RememberLink.name,
            schema: RememberLinkSchema
        }])
    ],
    controllers: [RememberPasswordController],
    providers: [RememberPasswordService],
    exports: [RememberPasswordService]
})
export class RememberPasswordModule {}
```

remember-password.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { UserDto } from 'src/users/dto/user.dto';
import { User } from 'src/users/schemas/users.schema';
import { RememberLinkDto } from './dto/rememberLink.dto';
import { RememberLink, RememberLinkDocument } from './schemas/rememberLink.schema';

@Injectable()
export class RememberPasswordService {

    constructor( @InjectModel(RememberLink.name) private readonly rememberLinkModel: Model<RememberLinkDocument> ) {}

    async getUserByRememberCode(code: string): Promise<UserDto> {
        return await this.rememberLinkModel.findOne({code}).populate(User.name).lean();
    }
}
```

Error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RememberPasswordService (?).
> Please make sure that the argument RememberLinkModel at index [0] is
> available in the RememberPasswordService context.

Comment: Are the paths on import statements correct?

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is export the MongooseModule as well, Its just that the dependency injection knows that there will be Separate module for that model somewhere in the App

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        MongooseModule.forFeature([{
            name: RememberLink.name,
            schema: RememberLinkSchema
        }])
    ],
    controllers: [RememberPasswordController],
    providers: [RememberPasswordService],
    exports: [MongooseModule,RememberPasswordService] // <-- MongooseModule added here
})
export class RememberPasswordModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. It was import "RememberPasswordService" instead of "RememberPasswordModule" in another module